# How to create new user and set the privilege for this account on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

How to create new user and set the privilege for this account on windows 8?

Since 3 of my family share the same computer, and I hope I could keep their privacy from each other.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The short version:

- Start, Settings, Users, Add a user
- Check "This is a child's account"

---

## Create a new user

To create a new user, open Start and search for `Users` under `Settings`.

[image]

This should open up to the `PC settings` page on the `Users` tab

[image]

---

### Add another user

Select `Add user` under `Other Users`

[image]

Complete the `Add a user` wizard. There should be an option to set up family safety, but if you miss it our it doesn't show simply:

---

## Limit the account privileges

Once you've finished adding the new user, open Start and search for `Change account type`
[image]

---

### Select the user you would like to change

Click on the account you would like to modify

[image]

### Change account type

Then select `Change account type` and choose 'Standard'.
[image]

---

#### Manage another account

You should return to the following screen, select `Manage another account.`
[image]

## Family safety

Now choose `Set up Family Safety` and configure appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Oddly when I set up a new account it did not initially show up in the 'Modify accounts' bit. After a minute or so it showed up. Not sure if this happens to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The process for creating local (non Microsoft Live) accounts is the same as in Windows 7, for the most part. You can link accounts to Live at a latter stage as well if you want.

My preferred way to add accounts is through the Computer Management.

Open it by typing `compmgmt.msc` on that Start Screen or right clicking Computer in Explorer and choosing Manage.

Expand "Local Users and Groups", right click "Users" and choose "New User."

[image]

Fill out the form, click create. You will have a new user that has no Admin rights. If you want to muck around with group for permissions, etc. you can do that from this console as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the charms bar.
2. Click on the search button (first button)
3. Click on settings.
4. Search for "Create an account".
5. Click "Add a new user in PC Settings".
6. Scroll down and click "Add a new user".
7. Choose whether the account be a Microsoft account or Local Account.
8. When finished go to the search again and search for "Make changes to accounts"

If a local account:
1. Click on user.
2. Click on "Change the account type".
3. Make sure that it is a Standard user.

If Microsoft account:
Not sure about here. Just testing.

Comment: once a local account is created, you can link it to a M$ account upon login.