# Does Windows 8 provide guest user functionality

Tags: windows-8, multiple-users, guest-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create new user and set the privilege for this account on windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/498041/how-to-create-new-user-and-set-the-privilege-for-this-account-on-windows-8)

One of the great functionalists windows has been offering for long is multi-user login. Different people can share the same PC with their own flair along with a guest user login. But, I am not sure, if this feature is available on Windows 8 or not. I have read many posts, articles but no where find anything related to this feature.

Is the feature missing, or restrained on Windows 8 due to which no one is talking about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guest account can indeed be enabled, as can be seen in the following guide from [forum.technical-assistance.co.uk](http://forum.technical-assistance.co.uk/activating-the-guest-account-in-windows-8-vt1795.html):

> By default the guest account in Windows 8 is turned off.
>
> To activate
>   it is much the same as Windows 7, just getting there is a little
>   different.
>
> Open the Control Panel by typing Control on a blank part of the Start
>   screen and pressing Enter,
>
> [image: Control Panel]
>
> In Category view click on Add or remove user accounts.
>
> [image: Add/remove accounts]
>
> You will see the Guest account and the fact that it is turned off,
>   double click on it.
>
> [image: Guest account turned off]
>
> Click on 'Turn On' and its activated, close the Control panel and log
>   off or reboot to test your Guest account if you wish.
>
> [image: Turn on]
>
> The next time you Start your machine or logoff you will be given the
>   option to log onto the Guest account or your normal account.
>
> To turn it off again log in with your account.  Navigate back to the
>   User accounts as per above.  Click on the 'Guest' account image and
>   you will be given the option to turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

Its the same as in Windows 7.

Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts -> Manage Accounts
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the guest account functionality still exists in Windows 8 but is disabled by default.  I have yet to find an official doc on Microsoft's site regarding this.  Visit the User Accounts section of the control panel to re enable the guest account.

Comment: It was the same (Guest disabled by default) in Win7 as well (and possibly Vista too, but not sure).