# How to see what privileges my user account has in Win 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts

Is there any way to see clearly what privileges my user account does and doesn't have in Windows 8.1 Pro?

I've been through everything I can find in both the desktop Control Panel user accounts section and in that swipey touchscreen alternate settings section, and can't find anything relevant.

I'm not sure if user accounts are 100% binary ("standard" or "administrator" and nothing in between) or if individual accounts can be granted specific privileges. Either way, I'd like to find out what my account is.

In the "Desktop" control panel, I've tried accessing `Change account type` aka `Advanced User Accounts Control Panel`, which [I gather lists accounts and their status](https://superuser.com/questions/498041/how-to-create-new-user-and-set-the-privilege-for-this-account-on-windows-8?rq=1), but I can't access this ("This action requires elevation"). Does this mean I have a 100% "Standard" account, or is it possible I might have certain non-standard privileges, but not the ability to modify user account privileges? Is such a thing possible in Win 8.1?

---

I'm asking because I'm having an issue where IT support claim to have granted admin rights for my account, but for many things, when using my account to approve a change, I get an error message "This action requires elevation". I'd like to see precisely what the status of my account is - what rights my account has, and what rights it doesn't have.

---

*(if it's relevant, this is an active desktop network account on an office (exchange?) server on a domain)*

Comment: Is the PC in question on a domain?

Comment: Yes, it is, and it's Win 8.1 Pro which I gather is relevant for something to do with domain binding

Answer (score 1):

In a command prompt enter

```
 whoami /all
```

This will show your unelevated privileges. Do the same thing for Command Prompt (Admin) on the Windowskey+X menu to see the privileges you have running elevated.

[Whoami Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299(v=ws.10).aspx)